# Run Matlab code simultaneously

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing

I am trying to capture image from two cameras at the same  time, see the following matlab code:

```
cam1 = initCamera(1);
cam2 = initCamera(2);

image1 = cam1.getSnapshot();
image2 = cam2.getSnapshot();
```

because matlab process this code line by line, their is a slite delay between images obtained from the code.

i want to call "getSnapshot" instruction for both cameras synchronously because i want to get the images exactly at the same time from the two cameras.

Is there a way to do this in matlab? i tried to use `parfor` and `spmd` but i have issues with the camera objects variables scope.

Comment: I think you mean "asynchronously"

Comment: Related: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56686-asynchronous-video-reader

Comment: You are right, I mean asynchronously but simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel toolbox may help you.

```
matlabpool    % Use default parallel configuration
spmd          % By default uses all labs in the pool
    INP = load(['somedatafile' num2str(labindex) '.mat']);
    RES = somefun(INP);
end
```

`RES` on the labs are accessible from the client as `RES{1}` from lab 1, `RES{2}` from lab 2, etc.

Comment: i tried this method like this
spmd;
cam = initCamera(labIndex);
end;

spmd;
image = cam{labIndex}.getSnapshot();
end;

but it fails to get snapshot, it is look like after the spmd end all objects got freed. so the cam object is not intialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it running on each worker (i.e. `spmd`):

```
spmd
    cam = initCamera(labindex);
end

spmd
    img = cam.getSnapshot();
end

img{1};   % access first image
img{2};   % access second image, etc
```

Note that `cam` variable exists in each worker's workspace. It is not a sliced variable, so you do not need to index into it. You can get the result from each worker using cell array indexing, such as `img{1}` etc.

If you want to use `parfor`, you can do it like this:

```
parfor i = 1:2
    cam{i} = initCamera(i);
end

parfor i = 1:2
    img{i} = cam{i}.getSnapshot();
end

img{1};   % access first image
img{2};   % access second image
```